# Stuck in infinite loop with simple akka-http route test with actors

Tags: scala, akka, infinite-loop, akka-http, akka-actor

I have a simple example where I have a route that invokes an actor, however it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop and the http response never comes. I am using akka-actor version 2.6.15 and akka-http version 10.2.4. Here is the sample code, any help is appreciated.

```
package test

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, Props}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{Route, _}
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.{RouteTestTimeout, ScalatestRouteTest}
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.scalatest.Matchers
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpec

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

case class TestMessage()

class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => "response"
  }
}

class AkkaHttpTest extends AnyWordSpec with Matchers with ScalatestRouteTest {
  val testActor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor()), name = "TestActor")
  implicit val timeout: Timeout = 15.seconds
  implicit val defaultTimeout = RouteTestTimeout(15.seconds)
  val route: Route = {
    get {
      pathSingleSlash {
        complete((testActor ? TestMessage()).mapTo[String])
      }
    }
  }

  "Test" should {
    "Return text" in {
      Get() ~> route ~> check {
        println(responseAs[String])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reply to a message in Akka, you have to explicitly send the reply.

In your example:

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case _ =>
    sender ! "response"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it!